# Syncing calendar events between Android and iOS applications and user calendars?

Tags: android, ios, calendar, synchronization, android-calendar

I have an app on both Android and iOS which allows the user to put appointments on their calendar. Currently for both platforms, I'm simply adding the appointment to the default calendar. If the user has their iCal set up to sync with Google calendar, adding events in iOS will cause those to show up on their calendar on Android, and vice versa. Now, however, I need to add multiple user support for the app, and have their events kept separate. I am looking for a way to sync the calendar events between my app on both platforms.

How do I reliably retrieve calendar events across devices?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific question? Otherwise it's hard to help you.

However, I can point in you in the direction of [CalDav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV), which is the backing implementation that most calendar sync platforms use.

As for specifics:

Since you mentioned below that this is for a doctor's office, do keep in mind that if you're in the US, you should comply to HIPAA.

You'll need a backend server, since you're not going to want to sync that information to Google Calendars. A quick Google search comes up with [Radicale](http://radicale.org/), but there are others in the CalDAV link above.

You'll also need to move away from the system calendar frameworks (since I believe they only work on the subscribed calendars) and use a more general CalDAV framework (also in the above link).

In short, you'll have to deploy a WebDAV service that supports calendars, and sync to that. Then when you switch local users, you re-authenticate to that server with the new user and download their calendars.

Comment: Yes. My specific question is how to reliably retrieve events from a user's calendar on multiple devices.

Comment: @s73v3r Can you give more information on the app? What's its purpose? Do you have a backing web server? Do you want multiple _local_ users (as in multiple people using the same device)?

Comment: This part of the app is used to keep track of doctor's appointments. There is a backing web server, but it doesn't do anything regarding the actual appointment date. And we do need multiple local users.

Comment: @s73v3r Added some information, let me know if you have any questions or need any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to implement your own back end to keep track of the events and users.

You'll need to model the users and events that correspond to the google users and events.

To develop your backend you could either choose some web platform (Ruby on Rails, Node.js etc) or if you lack the time / experience you could use some [Back End As A Service provider](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20482/how-to-choose-the-best-backend-provider-for-your-ios-app-parse-vs-stackmob-vs-appcelerator-cloud-and-more) (like [parse](https://parse.com/) for example).

Comment: Suppose the user edits the event in their Calendar, instead of the app?

Comment: In that case you should also get an OAuth token and sync data using Google's calendar API (see https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/)

Comment: Wouldn't that require the users to have Google Calendar accounts?